# I have installed libdbd-mysql-perl on ubuntu 14 and I get a crazy Version required

Tags: 14.04, mysql, perl

Error message:

> DBI version v10.0.33.6 required--this is only version v1.636.0 at /usr/share/perl/5.18/Exporter/Heavy.pm line 106.

Given that v1.636.0 is the latest version I REALLY cannot get a version 10. Where is the message actually originating and how do I fix it.

Ubuntu version 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. I have never noticed this behaviour before but it is quite obvious when you see it!

I omitted the semi-colon to end the use DBI line, so it too the next valid looking string as the version requirement!